# Dropdown toggle only working on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap's dropdown. It's a simple process, here is how it works:

If user hovers "add to cart" button when no size has been selected it will change the text in the buttons `<span>` to "select size". If user clicks button when the span text is "select size" it should toggle the bootstrap dropdown. Here is the code:

```
var size = true;

$('#cart-btn').mouseenter(function(){
 if(size==true){
  $(this).find('span').html('NEED SIZE');
  }
});

$('#cart-btn').mousedown(function(){
 if(size==true){
   $(".cart-dd.dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
  }
});

$('#cart-btn').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('span').html('ADD TO CART');
});
```

Dropdown toggle will not fire (toggle/open) if I use `.click` or `.mouseup` it will only fire on `.mousedown` why is this?

NOTE: I have an additional bit of code here:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li label").click(function(){
  var selected = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('#cart-dd').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selected);
  size = false;
});
```

This changes the the label of the dropdown (is pretty much irrelevant, but might be causing conflict?)

Answer (score 0):

Change your functions mouseenter, mousedown, mouseleave to:

For older Jquery

```
$("#cart-btn").live("mousedown mouseenter mouseleave",function(){//dosomething});
```

For newest jquery:

```
$("#cart-btn").on("mousedown mouseenter mouseleave",function(){//dosomething});
```